# What is the first step to using a REST API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have just completed Hartl's book on rails. Following the examples have been helpful and I have been able to build some very basic functionality for my app.  However, there is this API I would like to use, and have been granted a key for the API.  I have absolutely no idea how to start implementing the API.  The other stuff surrounding API's have been helpful, but I literally am stuck on what the very first step should be to begin implementing the API.

I need for a user to be able to sign up and authenticate, then supply data that will be tracked through the external API.  I've got the user sign up and authenticate stuff down pat, just need to know what the very first baby step to using this API should be.

The logic behind the answer would be equally helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActiveResource for your model and point it to the external API. This is useful if your model uses an external data source.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

If the external API you want to use is a well known, there is a good chance that there is already a gem for interaction with that API.

If you only need to send some data to the external API but your model does not use it as its source, you can use an HTTP client like Faraday https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday