# How to use external APIs in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm tring to use an external API, but found no clue of it.

http://open.youku.com/docs/api/videos/show_basic

It seems like I have to build sth from scratch, so How can I start? Is there any example using external API that I can refer to?

I just find these maybe helpful:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api

[What is the first step to using a REST API in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379834/what-is-the-first-step-to-using-a-rest-api-in-rails)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTParty makes it pretty simple to consume JSON APIs. here's an example: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty

Note that the twitter examples that are around the web generally don't work anymore because twitter.

Answer (score 0):

There is gem better than this named as REST CLIENT.In this u can access a rest-web service easily
ex)

1. get  a=RestClient.get 'get Service'
2. post b=RestClient.post 'post service',params