# I Want to Implement the PayPal Digital Goods Express Checkout API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, paypal

I want to sell a PDF booklet in my Rails 4 application by adding a button on my store view.  I looked at some of the PayPal documentation about how to set up each piece of the transaction in the API.  However none of it gives details on how to implement an API solution manually using specific platforms.

I have searched questions in Stack Overflow.  None of them relate to Rails, Digital Goods and Express Checkout.  I found out about a gem rails-api but that is only for API only applications which mine is not.

This is my first time attempting to implement a 3rd-party API in Rails.  I have not set up my PayPal account for Express Checkout yet.  I want to know what steps to take to implement a 3rd-party API in Rails before I get started.

I searched on how to implement an API in Rails but have not found any specific information other than the [paypal-express gem](https://github.com/nov/paypal-express) and this link [What is the first step to using a REST API in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379834/what-is-the-first-step-to-using-a-rest-api-in-rails).  When I read the [wiki](https://github.com/nov/paypal-express/wiki) for the paypal-express gem I did not find where I'm supposed to add the code for the API anywhere.

UPDATE: I decided to look at the PayPal developer page again and after some time I found that they recommend the [rest-api-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby).  However the documentation give examples on how to implement this using a Model which is not what I want to do.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will keep searching.  I may also see if Square has an API for digital goods that may be a lot easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the idea on implementing the Express Checkout API.  I decided to continue to search for solutions where I could use a PayPal button for digital goods to no avail.

My husband found a solution called [FetchApp](http://www.fetchapp.com) which is free for up to 1 MB of storage.  You just add your PayPal account email address that you want the payments to go to.

They have other options with a small monthly fee with unlimited products and bandwidth depending on the amount of storage you need for your files.  I opted for the $5/month option for 25MB.  This is way more than I need for my booklet.  There are no additional fees that the company charges.  They may ask you to upgrade if they see you consistently have an incredibly high volume of downloads per month.

They also have a $10/month option where instead of uploading your files to their servers they will update your account where you can put links to your digital items.  They will mask your links and gather stats on your links.

It took me about an hour to set up and test my new account.  I copied code for the Buy Now button for my booklet.  When clicked the PayPal window opens as normal. When the payment is processed FetchApp sends an email to your customer with the download link.  The email is customizable. You can request to get an email sent to you notifying you of orders.  The service also keeps track of what is purchased and downloaded from your account.

Here is a YouTube video on [how quick it is to set this up](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RWcuGgXx38).

This product was the first product produced from Shopify.  To think I was considering checking out PayPal developers to get this done.  These folk were smart to develop a service like this that is easy to implement and evidently has a very high satisfaction rate.  Hopefully this product will be available for a very long time.